# jqplot js breaks my jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm using [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/smoothedLine.html) to do some Graphs, and they work fine, but I'm trying to use the 'smooth' attribute in order to smooth out the lines but when I add the js files, my jquery breaks. and I don't know why. I'm running it on FF and firebug doesn't seem to show me any errors.

These are the js files I was using to draw the graphs ( which work fine)

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jqplot/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/miloWeb/css/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css" media="screen" />
```

but then I add these in, the jquery breaks .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jqplot/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/miloWeb/css/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />
```

the way I'm building the graph is like this:

```
$( "#chartPointsBmi" ).dialog( "open" );
                  var plot2 = $.jqplot('bmiChartDiv', coordinates, {
                       title:'BMI/Time Graph',
                      gridPadding:{right:35},
                      axes:{
                        xaxis:{
                          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                          tickOptions:{formatString:'%b %#d, %y'},
                         // min:'May 01, 2011',
                          tickInterval:'1 year'
                        },
                        yaxis:{  
                          min:0,
                          max:40,
                          tickInterval:'5'
                        }
                      },
                      series:[{lineWidth:5, rendererOptions: {smooth: true}, markerOptions:{style:'filledCircle'}}]
                  });
```

Any ideas as to why they're not playing along?? Thanks!

~Myy

**EDIT:**

here's the rendered html

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/miloWeb/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/miloWeb/css/style.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/miloWeb/css/view.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/miloWeb/css/ezmark.css" media="screen" />



    <!--[if IE]>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            /* place css fixes for all versions of IE in this conditional comment */
            .milo #content { zoom: 1; }
            /* the above proprietary zoom property gives IE the hasLayout it may need to avoid several bugs */
        </style>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jquery.ezmark.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/random.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jquery.maxlength-min.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".button").button();
        });

        function loading(){
            $( "#loadingPopUp" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        }

        function unloading(){
            $( "#loadingPopUp" ).dialog( "close" );
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jqplot/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jqplot/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/miloWeb/css/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.css" /> 


    <script language="javascript">
```

Comment: Can you confirm that JQuery is not included twice? The 3 libs declaration which break JQuery described in your post constain a JQuery declaration. Is it really normal?

Comment: I added the rendered html, I don't see where the problem might be. I don't see any duplicate libraries.

Comment: Can you make a one complete sample at for example http://jsfiddle.net so we could see the problem? Turning a line into a smoothed one doesn't really require additional plugins.

Comment: You need to load jquery before loading jquery.jqplot...

Comment: It works fine to do straight lines, it breaks when I add <script type="text/javascript" src="/miloWeb/js/jqplot/jquery.min.js"></script> , so I'm guessing it conflicts with anotehr jquery file. It doesn't show me the 'smooth' lines

Comment: Huh?  Isn't jquery.min.js jquery itself?  Are you loading jquery in any of the 5 files you load before it?